# Filling and Styling D3 Tree nodes based off of data

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tree

stuck on styling the Collapsible Tree example found at

D3 Code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

JSON: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083
(but instead of *size*, using *number* set to some single digit integer )

So far, I've modified index.html:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)

*.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });*
```

TO

```
.style("stroke", function(d) { return d.status > 0 ? "green" : "red";})
```

I want the node to fill red in the case the *number* datum equals something greater than 1, and green if it is zero.

On top of this, if some kind soul could also

1. entertain a third condition (i.e. a negative number)
2. direct me how to fill the colors on the ancestor nodes based off of the children nodes

I've absolutely SCOURED all my online resources so any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `the number datum equals something greater than 1`... it would be good if you add your json object so we can see what are you talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you really need, but I think you added a property `status` to you json object and according to its value you are giving a different circles color to the corresponding element.

> 1. entertain a third condition (i.e. a negative number)

While appending your circles you can set each circle's style as following :

If the item's status is greater than 1 than set `stroke` proprety to red else if it is equal to zero than to green else (if it is a negative number ) than to orange for example.

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
         .attr("r", 1e-6)
         .style("stroke",
              function(d) { 
                 /*return color according to the current data's status value    */
                 /*it is > 1 than red else if < 0 than orange else(if 0)than red */   
                  return d.status >= 1 ? 
                         "red" 
                         :( d.status < 0 ? "orange" : "green")
              }) ;
```

> 2. direct me how to fill the colors on the ancestor nodes based off of the children nodes

I think you want to set the `fill` proprety of each circle having children to the same color as the `stroke` proprety.

So while looping the created circles you have to check if the current item has children if it is the case, set `fill` proprety to same color of `stroke` proprety like this:

```
nodeUpdate.select("circle")
          .attr("r", 4.5)
          .style("fill",
                 function(d) { 
                     /*check if children proprety exists for the current if yes 
                       get its stoke color and set fill proprety it this value */
                    return d._children ? d3.select(this).style('stroke') : "" ;
                 }) ;
```

#### Complete code:

```js
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 750,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var flare ={
              "name": "positive with children",
              "status":3,
              "children": [
              {
                "name": "zero with children",
                "status":0,
                 "children": [
                   {
                    "name": "positive with children",
                    "status":1,
                    "children": [
                      {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 3938,"status":3},
                      {"name": "negative with no children", "size": 3812,"status":-1},
                      {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 6714,"status":1}
                    ]
                   },
                   {
                     "name": "negative with children",
                     "status":-2,
                     "children": [
                       {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 3534,"status":1},
                       {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 5731,"status":6}
      
                     ]
                   }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "name":"postive with children",
                  "status":1,
                   "children": [
                   {"name": "negative with no children", "size": 599,"status":-3},
                   {"name": "zero with no children", "size": 386,"status":0},
                   {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 323,"status":3},
                   {"name": "zero with no children", "size": 307,"status":0}
                   ]
                },
                 {
                  "name":"negative with children",
                  "status":-3,
                   "children": [
                   {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 335,"status":1},
    {"name": "negative with no children", "size": 383,"status":-1},
    {"name": "zero with no children", "size": 874,"status":0},
    {
     "name": "positive with children",
     "status":1,
     "children": [
      {"name": "positive with no children", "size": 3165,"status":1},
      {"name": "zero with no children", "size": 2815,"status":0},
      {"name": "negative with no children", "size": 3366,"status":-2}
     ]
    }
                   ]
                }
            ]
      };
  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

       nodeEnter.append("circle")
              .attr("r", 1e-6)
              .style("stroke", function(d) { return d.status >= 1 ? "red" : ( d.status < 0 ? "orange" : "green")  }) ;
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      //.style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
       .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? d3.select(this).style('stroke') : "";}) ;
  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```